# Best answers don't update - ever

Tags: support, status-bydesign, jobs

On my profile, there are answers with just a couple of votes while I've given better answers (more upvoted ones), which never showed up there. I don't believe these answers displayed on my profile ever changed since the careers profile was created.

Shouldn't these be updated every some time?

Comment: Aren't those answers selected by hand?

Comment: @Bobby - yeah, but the highest-rated ones are pre-filled when you first start out, so that's likely the source of confusion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Top Answers" are answers that are supposed to best represent you as a candidate, not necessarily those which have been most up voted (although it stands to reason that they may be one in the same, in many cases). As far as I know, the system isn't meant to automatically update them, even *if* it did some prefilling originally.

Thankfully though, you have full control over what's displayed there:

[image: Careers profile top answer controls]

If you want to remove the existing answers, use the red × in the top right corner to take them out of the list. If you want to add new answers you feel are better candidates, use the "add an answer" link at the bottom. If you choose to display multiple answers, you can sort them to your liking using the arrow(s) next to the remove button.

Comment: Good answer.  I'd be pissed if I ever gave a funny answer to some silly joke question (thankfully unlikely in the current SO climate) and that answer suddenly sky-rocketed to the top of my careers profile

Comment: You can even change the order of the answers.

Answer (score 7):

The answers on your careers profile are selected by *you*. They are there to show off what *you* think are your best answers.

If *you* think you've given better answers, *you* have to update your profile.

Answer (score 4):

No. Top answers are selected by you. When you first create your profile we put your top 7 most highly voted answers from Stack Overflow on your profile as a convenience. We expect that you might have other answers you'd want to show off though, so we give you the ability to add and remove whatever you want from this section as Tim lined out in his answer.